# JPA unidirectional one to many with join table - entity mapping not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have tried to create some JPA Entities for a DB designed with the following tables: *PRINCIPALS* and *CREDENTIALS* which have the following relations with other tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CREDENTIALS")
public class Credentials {

    @Id   
    @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_ID")
    private Integer credentialID;

    @Id   
    @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_TYPE_ID")
    private String credentialTypeID;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREDENTIAL_TYPE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private CredentialTypes credentialTypes;  
}
```

- *CREDENTIALS* has a *oneToOne* relation with *CREDENTIAL_TYPES*

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "CREDENTIAL_TYPES")
  public class CredentialTypes {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_TYPE_ID")
      private String credentialTypeID;

      @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
      private String description;
  }
  ```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRINCIPALS")
public class Principals implements Serializable {

    @Id   
    @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private String principalTypeID;

    @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_ID", nullable = false)
    private String principalID;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PrincipalTypes principalTypes;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "PRINCIPAL_CREDENTIAL",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CREDENTIAL_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRINCIPAL_ID"))
    private List<Credentials> credentials;
```

- *PRINCIPALS* has a *oneToOne* relation with *PRINCIPAL_TYPES*

  ```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPES")
    public class PrincipalTypes implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private String principalTypeID;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
  ```
- And finally *PRINCIPALS* has a *oneToMany* relation with *CREDENTIALS* and uses a join table *PRINCIPLE_CREDENTIAL*

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "PRINCIPAL_CREDENTIAL")
  public class PrincipalCredential implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
  private String principalTypeID;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "PRINCIPAL_ID", nullable = false)
  private String principalID;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_ID")
  private Integer credentialID;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "CREDENTIAL_TYPE_ID")
  private String credentialTypeID;
  ```

At startup (using SpringBoot) I receive an error for the oneToMany relation between Principals and Credentials and just don't have any idea how to fix it... Tried various other methods (The DB design cannot be changed).

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering entities.Principals from entities.Credentials has the wrong number of column. should be 2
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:502)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1467)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1233)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:794)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:85
```

I find the exception wierd because there is no refering of Principlas from Credentials....

Comment: That's got to be the worst naming I've ever seen. I'm confused and I'm not a program.

Comment: Well...yes the tables names are confusing but that was the given model so nothing I can do to change that :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRINCIPLE_TYPE_ID and CREDENTIAL_TYPE_ID are missing in the joinColumns/inverseJoinColumns. I think you must use the @JoinColumns Annotation

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem and the exception message was relevant though :)